# Img-thumbnail does not maintain aspect ratio

Tags: css, html, image, bootstrap-4, thumbnails

I am trying to create a table with some user details, like the user picture, email, age, etc.

The problem I have is that the thumbnail image does not have the normal aspect ratio. Also, I am using a gravatar link for the source of the image, with a certain size (50).

You can see the problem in the pictures attached below.

[This is how it's looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxpjd.png)

[This is how I would like it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPMdU.png)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
<main id="main" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <table class="table table-responsive">
           <thead>
             <th>Picture</th>
             <th>Other info</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 <div class="media">
                   <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=identicon&s=50">
                 </div>
               </td>
               <td>
                 Other info (email, age, username etc.)
               </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>           
</div>
```

You can find the problem and an example code in this JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/caw4qyk0/5/

I can only see the problem happening in Firefox.

Is there a way this can be fixed? Without specifying a specific width and height? 
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is the issue. The div with class `media` that is wrapped around the image element has `display: flex` which will have an effect on the dimensions of child elements. I used the jsfiddle you provided and got the image to display as a perfect square in Firefox with the addition of `height: 50px;` on any of the classes on the image itself.

Comment: But if I add an extra div containing those attributes https://jsfiddle.net/p9n0k6oc/, wrapping the image, the aspect ratio is correct. Also, why would the display:flex only be an issue in Firefox?

Comment: Flex box affects the direct child elements of a wrapper with `display: flex` on it. That's why adding another wrapper also works. Firefox has a slightly different spec for Flexbox, all browsers have slightly different specs still... check out the usage chart: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex.
For even more info on how flexbox works, this article rocks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: In case you don't specify a height in the flex container, how does the flex container know what to set the height to? Also, I don't get why adding a wrapper div works, because presumably the outer div should still be resized by the flex container, hence also the image included within.

Comment: Even if the outer div gets resized by the flex container the image element inside is now no longer a flex child element (the div you added does not have `display: flex`), so it behaves as expected. Read the CSS-Tricks article, it explains the nuances of flexbox better than I could. I have had that article bookmarked for reference for years.